# Truncate wxFile (set lesser length)

Tags: file, cross-platform, wxwidgets, truncate

I'm looking for a safe and cross-platform way to truncate a file to a specified size > 0 (lesser length when file's current length). It was very easy in Delphi:

```
Seek(f,position);
Truncate(f);
```

I'm surprised there is no method for this in `wxFile` class.

Using temporary file to copy contents is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no such method, you need to call `ftruncate(f.fd())` yourself under Unix or `SetEndOfFile()` under Windows.